# SQL distribute data between tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a very large database.

The data will contain relationships between items.

I was wandering if I could get better performance using smaller tables. I think that doing operations to select item relationships on a large table might be less efficient than selecting only the tables with the items I want.

**Example**:

*Option 1*:

tableItems:
item1 | item2 | score

Options 2:

*tabelItem1*

item2 | score

Eventually when the data is filled I'll have an n<sup>2</sup> table with all the scores between the items, so if I want to find of item1 in relation to other items I think it would be more efficient to extract the data from a dedicated table (rather than do a select on a huge n<sup>2</sup> table).

Is this a good solution ? or is there some SQL optimization that will work better ?

Comment: Are the items dynamic or static....

Comment: are you saying you want to create a table for every item#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 because it's normalized.

With option 2 (if I understand corerctly), you'll have a few (thousands?) tables, one for every item? **No, no, no** to that.

JOINs are your friends. Plan your queries and the indexes you'll need for them and then start thinking about partitioning or clusters for when (and if) your database will grow huge.

Comment: "JOINs are your friends."  They can be.  They can also be your enemy.  It depends on if they are used correctly and what the requirements are.

Answer (score 5):

i think one table - then use indexing and partitioning to optimize.

Answer (score -3):

Joining tables is slow.

I've seen over-normalization paralyze a project.

Comment: Joining tables is slow compared to what?

Comment: @ypercube hippies, compared to hippies.

Comment: "Joining tables is slow compared to what?"   Compared to not joining tables.  Over-nomalization is bad.  The 3rd normal form seems to be the optimum.

Comment: I agree on over-normalization. The OP's question though was about under-normalization (below 1st normal form).